# How to add Horizontal Scrollbar to drop down list control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have one Drop down list box like following : 
         
               ITEM AJLSDKLFJASDKLFJSDKLFJDKLFJ
              
             aklsjdfkjdklfjla fjklfdjfj ajlfjad
             564897fadfadfdff897897 564 564 565656               
             Small String skdkjk
             Long String sklfjasdkljfklfjaklfjkljfklajfljkljklfajlfjsd
             aasdfaklfjla fjklfdjfj ajlfjad
            
             asdfasfssdfasdfas 565656

```
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

when drop downlist has item string too large then i want to give it horizontal Scrollbar ...

How can i give this...
Please Tell me solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Look into AjaxControlToolkit for some alternatives that might work for you.